# How can I align logos horizontally with the respective text underneath the logos?

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to align logos horizontally with the respective text underneath them so they look nice and in order. Currently, they are just vertical. I have searched this site and many others, and tried different solutions but nothing seems to work. Here is my code.

```css
.intro-text {
 color: #000000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

.intro-text-3d {
 color: #000000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

.intro-text-process {
 color: #000000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

.intro-text-toolset {
 color: #000000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

/** Logos **/

.logos-all {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 5%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: .95em;
}

strong {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

section h4 {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<article>
            <section>
                <p class="intro-text">
                  Some text goes here.
                 </p></div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/79" alt="CSS3" height="80" width="79"/>
                        <strong>CSS3</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/79" alt="Javascript" height="80" width="79"/>
                        <strong>Javascript</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/79" alt="Wordpress" height="80" width="79"/>
                        <strong>Wordpress</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/79" alt="PhP" height="80" width="79"/>
                        <strong>PhP</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                <p class="intro-text-3d">
                 Some text goes here
                </p>
                <div class="logos-all">
                   <div>
                    <img src="img/3ds max-logo.png" alt="3ds Max" height="80" width="79"/>
                       <strong>3DS MAX</strong>
                   </div>
                   <div>
                    <img src="img/c4d-logo.png" alt="Cinema 4D" height="80" width="79"/>
                       <strong>Cinema 4D</strong>
                   </div>
                   <div>
                    <img src="img/blender-logo.png" alt="Blender 3D" height="80" width="79"/>
                       <strong>Blender</strong>
                   </div>
                </div>
                </section>
            <section>
                <h4>How the process works</h4>
                <p class="intro-text-process">Some text goes here  </p>
            </section>
            <section>
             <h4>Design Toolset</h4>
                <p class="intro-text-toolset">Some text goes here.</p>
                <div class="logos-all">
                <div>
                 <img src="img/photoshop-logo.png" alt="Photoshop" height="80" width="79"/>
                    <strong>Photoshop</strong>
                </div>
                <div>
                 <img src="img/illustrator-logo.png" alt="Illustrator" height="80" width="79"/>
                    <strong>Illustrator</strong>
                </div>
                <div>
                 <img src="img/gimp-logo.png" alt="Gimp" height="80" width="79"/>
                    <strong>Gimp</strong>
                </div>
                <div>
                 <img src="img/inkscape-logo.png" alt="Inkscape"/>
                    <strong>Inkscape</strong>
                </div>
                </div>
                </article>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use Bootstrap you can use bootstrap panel .

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="https://www.pushpraj.com/images/cool-scenery.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="error" width="384" height="236">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Title 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="https://www.pushpraj.com/images/cool-scenery.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="error" width="384" height="236">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Title 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <img src="https://www.pushpraj.com/images/cool-scenery.jpg" class="img-rounded" alt="error" width="384" height="236">
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Title 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your images are inline-block, you need to put `text-align: center` on the parent (the `<div>`).

**Alternatively:**
You could also make your images `display: block`

**Or using flexbox:**
Make your `<div>` `display: flex; flex-direction: column` and your image `width: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use floats to align blocks with images and text horizontally and text-align to align images and text inside them.

Overflow hidden inside section clears floats inside them, in case you'd want to have background on it and it wouldn't display properly.

```css
.intro-text {
 color: #000000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

.intro-text-3d {
 color: #000000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

.intro-text-process {
 color: #000000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

.intro-text-toolset {
 color: #000000;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}

/** Logos **/

.logos-all {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 5%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: .95em;
}

strong {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align: center;
}

section h4 {
 text-align: center;
}

section {
    overflow: hidden;
}

section > div {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 25%; /* 1/logos in row */
}
```

```html
<article>
            <section>
                <p class="intro-text">
                  Some text goes here.
                 </p></div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/79" alt="CSS3" height="80" width="79"/>
                        <strong>CSS3</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/79" alt="Javascript" height="80" width="79"/>
                        <strong>Javascript</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/79" alt="Wordpress" height="80" width="79"/>
                        <strong>Wordpress</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/80/79" alt="PhP" height="80" width="79"/>
                        <strong>PhP</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </section>
                <section>
                <p class="intro-text-3d">
                 Some text goes here
                </p>
                <div class="logos-all">
                   <div>
                    <img src="img/3ds max-logo.png" alt="3ds Max" height="80" width="79"/>
                       <strong>3DS MAX</strong>
                   </div>
                   <div>
                    <img src="img/c4d-logo.png" alt="Cinema 4D" height="80" width="79"/>
                       <strong>Cinema 4D</strong>
                   </div>
                   <div>
                    <img src="img/blender-logo.png" alt="Blender 3D" height="80" width="79"/>
                       <strong>Blender</strong>
                   </div>
                </div>
                </section>
            <section>
                <h4>How the process works</h4>
                <p class="intro-text-process">Some text goes here  </p>
            </section>
```